# How to echo selected option value first?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, selection

I have this drop down where i need to show the years.  I want to show the previously chosen seleciton first.  I am using this below but it shows me a blank instead of the chosen value...

Code:

```
 <select name="year">
 <option selected value="<?php echo $previousyear;?>">
 <?php for($i=date('Y'); $i>=1900; $i--)
    echo "<option value='$i' ".(($i == date('Y')?'selected="selected"':'')).">
 $i</option>";
 ?>
 </select></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: check out this, its similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511590/php-how-can-i-keep-the-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-to-stay-selected-on-subm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to replace in the code:

```
    <?php for($i=date('Y'); $i>=1900; $i--)
    echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `</option>` on that first option where you output $previousyear, so you're ending up generating:

```
<option selected value="XXX"><option value="2011" selected="selected">2011</option>
                             ^---missing </option>
```

You've now got **2** selected options, and most likely $previousyear is empty, causing the "empty" option.

Comment: ok i got the $variable to show but its not the one being selected.  it still shows 2011:  this is what i did: <option selected value="<?php echo $previousyear;?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $previousyear;?></option>

Comment: its not going to work because if you look at my query the echo "<option value='$i' ".(($i == date('Y')?'selected="selected"':'')).">
 $i</option>"; has selected.  How can i remove the selected to get teh query to work?

Comment: What'd you want to do is remove that first "hard-coded" option with the previous year, and make your in-loop comparison be `($i == $previousYear)` instead. There's no point in output two different options with the same year

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your current selection as a GET query and use it.

```
    if (isset($_GET['current'])) { 
      $previousyear = $_GET['current'];
    } 

<select name="year"> 
<option selected value="<?php echo $previousyear;?>">
```